# How to call functions in another function from Pyspark

Tags: python, function, pyspark, user-defined-functions, calling-convention

I need help on how to call TeamCt and SeniorCt functions and get the two total values into def Main function using Python Pyspark.

```
def Main(source1):

    
def TeamCt(source1):
    north_total = source1 
        .filter(F.col(‘team’) == ‘North’) 
        .groupBy(F.col(‘team’)) 
        .agg(F.count(‘*’).alias(‘n_total’)
    return north_total

def SeniorCt(source1):
    senior_total = source1 
        .filter(F.col(‘grade’) == ‘Senior’) 
        .groupBy(F.col(‘grade’)) 
        .agg(F.count(‘*’).alias(‘s_total’)
    return senior_total
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
def Main(source1):
    north_total = TeamCt(source1)
    senior_total = SeniorCt(source1)
```